# How to update one to many contents in a list?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

Say I have User which has some pets (which have a primary key).

```
class User : Object {
    let pets = List<Pet>()
}
```

Now I want to update the Pets in the list (from an API). How would I do that? Delete all Pets and insert the new ones? There is nothing like a `createOrUpdate()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method with create or update semantics on lists. But there is one for single objects on `Realm`. You can make use of that fact in different ways.

If you have already an user and get just an updated list of pets, you would need to clean up pets which are not referenced any more, remove all pets from the user, and then add all new pets.

```
let realm = …
let user = …
let newPetList = [["name": "Rex"], ["name": "Gustav"]]

// If pets can belong only to one user, you may want to delete them by:
realm.delete(user.pets)
// Alternatively you can just remove them from the updated user:
//user.pets.removeAll()

let newPets = newPetList.map { (newPetData) in
   return realm.create(Pet, newPetData, update: true)
}
user.pets.appendContentsOf(newPets)
```

If you get full updated user data and assuming your user has a primary key, then you could also use the create or update on the user directly:

```
class User : Object {
    dynamic var id: Int
    let pets = List<Pet>()

    class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

let userData = ["id": "23", "pets": [["name": "Rex"], ["name": "Gustav"]]]
let user = realm.create(User, userData, update: true)
```

But this will not take care of cleaning up possibly previously created Pets for that user.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
object.pets = // What you want

realm.write
{
  add(object, update: true)
}
```

See documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects)

Don't forget to define a primary key in your Model Class

Comment: I saw that, but what would be the assignment to object.pets? A new List will not work, since Lists are constants not variables as far as I see.

Comment: A new list. My example keep the same User object but change the pets list

Comment: I can only set a new list on the object, if the List is a variable, not a constant (var instead of let). But then the content is not persisted. Did I miss something? How do you declare the List property?

Comment: my declaration: dynamic var pets = List<Pet>()

Comment: List needs to be let (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2005) It can't work with var

Comment: My app is available in app Store and I use "dynamic var" declaration for List. If you know what to do why do you post question?